# ERROR: "invalid_client" with "AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

During authorisation of microsoft graph application using msal library,
I am getting below error:

```
"error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented.
"error_codes": [700025]
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: What kind of application is this?

Comment: It is web application

Comment: Ok, is this in back-end or front-end?

Comment: it's backend with django

Comment: Then either the app registration configuration has something wrong or your code. How are the redirect URIs configured?

Comment: App registration with redirect URIs is done under Single-Page application. As i will be using angular on the frontend

Comment: Ok, that sounds ok. In that case you will need to use MSAL.js / MSAL Angular in your front-end to do the authentication and acquire an access token for your back-end. Your Django back-end should implement JWT authentication and validate the access token sent by your front-end.

Comment: Ohh Okay! Let me try this. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your web application uses backend as Django and front end as Angular, you can use redirect URI platform as Single Page Application

You need to use MSAL.js Authentication in your SPA Application to acquire the access token.

Then your backend Django application validates the access token

**Note**: If you are using **MSAL.js v2.x**, you need to use authorization code flow

**Reference**: [Migrate JavaScript single-page app from implicit grant to authorization code flow - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-spa-implicit-to-auth-code)

Comment: I have tried this approach, but stuck at adding of redirect URI for SPA platform. My application url has '#' character in it. When i am adding it to redirect URI field, it is giving error: Fragments are not supported in redirect URIs. I cannot remove '#' from my url as it will affect other parts of the application. Do you have any solution?

Comment: the redirect uri cannot contain '#'. After login, you can redirect to your application homepage.